# Remove duplicates from array but ignoring one parameter

Tags: php, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

I have an array comprised of PHP objects as such:

```
$objects[0] => $object->type => 'President'
               $object->name => 'Joe Blogs'
               $object->address => '123 Harry Street'

$objects[1] => $object->type => 'Secretary'
               $object->name => 'Joe Blogs'
               $object->address => '123 Harry Street'

$objects[2] => $object->type => 'Treasurer'
               $object->name => 'Jane Doe'
               $object->address => '456 Upton Street'
```

I would like to ignore the `type` parameter and end up with:

```
$objects[0] => $object->type => 'President'
               $object->name => 'Joe Blogs'
               $object->address => '123 Harry Street'

$objects[2] => $object->type => 'Treasurer'
               $object->name => 'Jane Doe'
               $object->address => '456 Upton Street'
```

I have tried a few different things, one of which was to unset the parameter `type` using a `foreach` loop and then trying to reset it, but I wasn't sure how to tie the two indexes together to reset them. Another was trying to use the union in the select command but that wasn't working 100% correctly either.

I am just not sure how to best manage the `type` parameter.

**EDIT:**

I have tried to make the query a little easier, it now returns a list of IDs that I will get the address information later. This is the new array that I would like to filter out any duplicates.

```
    $items['president'][0] = '1'
                       [1] = '2'
                       [2] = '3'

    $items['secretary'][0] = '1'
                       [1] = '4'
                       [2] = '5'
```

What I would like is

```
$items['president'][0] = '1'
                   [1] = '2'
                   [2] = '3'

$items['secretary'][1] = '4'
                   [2] = '5'
```

Is that any better? (Note: I can use both array structures, but the second one would be better)

Comment: *I have tried a few difrent things* Show your attempt(s)

Comment: I have tried to explain my attempts but nothing was even close to working so I wont show my attempt code

Comment: So where are we with this question ?

Comment: We are travelling well, I have edited the select function to make the array a little better. Is that easier?

Comment: wow, now it's just a completely new array structure, what a trap.. I'm out

Comment: It's not meant to trap, I am just putting some thoughts out there to see what' less complicated. I can use either

Comment: Then if you use the first variant, does my answer works now or not: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31096442/3933332 ?

Comment: Yes, it does thanks. when working with your answer I realised that possibly the second array will allow me to do things a little better. I am so sorry to stuff you around. Do you know a way for the second structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

Here I just go through each object from `$objects`. Then I go through all of your unique objects from `$unique` with [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) and check if there is one object, which has the same values in `name` and `address` as the current one of the iteration.

If there in no object with the same values `name` and `address` in `$unique` I add it to it.

```
<?php

    $unique = [];

    foreach($objects as $o) {

        $duplicate = array_reduce($unique, function($keep, $v)use($o){
            if($v->name == $o->name && $v->address == $o->address)
                return $keep = TRUE;
        }, FALSE);

        if(!$duplicate)
            $unique[] = $o;

    }

    print_r($unique);

?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [type] => President
            [name] => Joe Blogs
            [address] => 123 Harry Street
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [type] => Treasurer
            [name] => Jane Doe
            [address] => 456 Upton Street
        )

)
```

**EDIT:**

As from your updated question with the new array structure, something like this should work:

Just like before you have an array with the unique values and also an array to keep track on which values you already have in your `$unique` array. Then you can just loop through your array an check if the value isn't already in the values array.

```
<?php

    $unique = [];
    $values = [];

    foreach($items as $keyOne => $arr) {

        foreach($arr as $keyTwo =>$v) {
            if(!in_array($v, $values)) {
                $unique[$keyOne][$keyTwo] = $v;
                $values[] = $v;
            }
        }
    }   

    print_r($unique);


?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [president] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

    [secretary] => Array
        (
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 5
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can just use array_unique, this function compares objects using the toString method:

```
class obj{
    public $type;
    public $name;
    public $address;

    public function __construct($type, $name, $address){
        $this->type = $type;
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->$address = $address;
    }

    public function __toString(){
        return $this->name . $this->address;
    }
}


$objects = array(
    new obj('President','Joe Bogs','123 Harry Street'),
    new obj('Treasurer','Joe Bogs','123 Harry Street'),
    new obj('Secretary','Jane Doh','456 Harry Street'),
);

// array_unique compares the toString value if given objects
$unique = array_unique($objects);
```

Or, if for some Reason you can not use __toString in your Object, write your own unique function that can compare using a custom function that returns a unique_id as you want it:

```
function custom_array_unique($array, $function){
    $res = array();
    foreach($array as $o){
        if(!isset($res[$function($o)])) {
            $res[$function($o)] = $o;
        }
    }
    return array_values($res);
}

$unique2 = custom_array_unique($objects, function($obj){
    return $obj->name . $obj->address;
});

var_dump($unique2);
```

Comment: But wont that see all three objects as unique as the $type is different?

Comment: No, i tried this, the idea is that array_unique compares each object to every other object in the array, if it is already there it will not produce it a second time in the result, however, as array_unique uses the __toString() function of an object ( if availabe ) to get a simpler String representation of the Object, and then compares the String representations instead of the objects itself, implementing that method in a way that fits your idea, ignoring the type will produce your expected result

Comment: However this may not be the most elegant solution, since you may want to use toString for something else, which is why i included the second example where you can define a function outside of the class that returns a special string that can then be compared.

Comment: Yes, that does make sense now, I don't have access to the __toString() function unfortunately.

Comment: @joschua011 I like the idea of your first code. But I think it's a bit of an overkill, to convert everything to the `obj` class, then take the unique values and then convert them back.

Comment: ok i see that, but in that case you could use the second example

Answer (score 0):

You can take the `type` as key, so it won't be duplicated, and in case you don't want to override, you can just verify it's existence by using [`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php), and after that you can [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to get the order as required, see example below:

```
$newArray = array();
foreach($objects as $object){
    if(!array_key_exists($object->name, $newArray)){
        $newArray[$object->name] = $object;
    }
}
$newArray = array_values($newArray);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($newArray);
```

Comment: make sure to leave reason for downvote, so if there are any mistakes, it can be corrected!

Comment: Besides the syntax errors in your code it also doesn't output OP's expected output. I think you missed that part: *I would like to **ignore the 'type'***

Comment: I think you also missed this part from my comment: *Besides the syntax error**s***

Comment: Then please tell me what: `$newArray();` should do? And also the output of your code still doesn't match the expected output from OP. (BTW: `array_values($newArray);` doesn't do what you think it does)